# fabricjs clipTo function is not being called or executed

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a simple script like:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) { 
        oImg.set({selectable:false})
        oImg.clipTo = function(ctx) {
            console.log("ctx")
            console.log(ctx)
        }
        console.log(oImg.clipTo)
    })
```

Here `oImg.clipTo` is doing nothing. `function(ctx){}` part is not evaluated.
But when I do `console.log(oImg.clipTo)` then `function(ctx){}` part is printed on the console.

Why `oImg.clipTo` is not executed here ?

Need help. I have gone throught tutorial of fabricjs but I found the same approach as mine..